# Regex optional characters at end of string

Tags: regex

I have this regex expressions:

`/^_string-(.*)-(-?[0-9]+)$/`

which would match 3 parts for this example:

'_string-hello-599' ['string-hello-599', 'hello', '599']

I would like to make the last part optional `-(-?[0-9]+)`, so that I could also match for example '_string-goodbye'.

This gives me 'unsafe regex' errors:

`/^_string-(.*)(-(-?[0-9]+))?$/`

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Did you mean to put `$` in front of `/`? Also, you need a lazy `.*?` in Group 2. Try just `/^_string-(.*?)(?:-(-?[0-9]+))?$/`

Comment: Or match word characters, and if you want to match a single hyphen make it optional as a whole part `^_string-(\w+)(-[0-9]+)?$`